# Function not working with webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, socialauth

This snippet is in my Business Logic Layer Class File:

```
Public Shared Function getAccIDFromSocialAuthSession() As Object
        Dim db As SqlDatabase = Connection.connection
        Dim accID As Integer
        If SocialAuthUser.IsLoggedIn Then
            Using cmd As SqlCommand = db.GetSqlStringCommand("SELECT AccountID FROM UserAccounts WHERE FBID=@fbID")
                db.AddInParameter(cmd, "fbID", SqlDbType.VarChar, SocialAuthUser.GetCurrentUser.GetProfile.ID)
                accID = db.ExecuteScalar(cmd)
            End Using
        End If

        Return accID
    End Function
```

I am using [SocialAuth.Net](http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-net/). `SocialAuth.NET` stores everything in session. For e.g to get the Facebook User ID we call `SocialAuthUser.GetCurrentUser.GetProfile.ID` , since it is session based i get this error message **"Object Reference Not Set to an instance of an object"** when i try to call `SocialAuthUser.GetCurrentUser.GetProfile.ID` from a webservice (asmx.vb) file. I am calling it like this **(ClassName.FunctionName-->BLL.getAccIDFromSocialAuthSession)**

Whaen i call the same function from a `aspx.vb` page it works fine but not when i call it from an `asmx.vb` page.

Since i do not know the session variable name , i cannot use `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("NameHere")`

Any solution??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the start of some working code:

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.ComponentModel

<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class LightboxService
    Inherits WebService

    <WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
    Public Function AddToLightbox(ByVal filename As String) As String
        Dim user As String = CStr(Session("username"))

'...etc.
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I owe you a pint. Add it to your list !! Thanks Man.

Comment: +1 - I had forgotten the EnableSession:=True in the webmethod call. good catch.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to implement `Implements IRequiresSessionState` on your service class.

Without this, no amount of calling `HttpContext.Current.Session("NameHere")` will work.

Example: (Pseudo-code)

```
    <WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
    <WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> 
    <System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()>
    Public Class MyService
            Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService
            Implements IRequiresSessionState '' <-- This is the part you need

            '' Code in here
    End Class
```

**UPDATE**

I haven't been able to clarify, though it might just not work with your webservice. Web services are stateless. Meaning it runs independently from your actual web site. So where ever `SocialAuthUser` has been instantiated the webserver will no nothing about it. It's there to run it's own stand-alone piece of code.

**Another Update**

Rather than use a web service for this case, try using a webmethod on your .aspx page codebehind.

So something like this:

```
     <ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> <Services.WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
     Public Shared Function getAccIDFromSocialAuthSession() As Object
          Dim db As SqlDatabase = Connection.connection
          Dim accID As Integer
          If SocialAuthUser.IsLoggedIn Then
              Using cmd As SqlCommand = db.GetSqlStringCommand("SELECT AccountID FROM UserAccounts WHERE FBID=@fbID")
                  db.AddInParameter(cmd, "fbID", SqlDbType.VarChar, SocialAuthUser.GetCurrentUser.GetProfile.ID)
                  accID = db.ExecuteScalar(cmd)
              End Using
          End If

        Return accID
    End Function
```

Comment: In debugger can you see which object is actually `nothing` from `SocialAuthUser.GetCurrentUser.GetProfile.ID`. I.E is it `ID` or `SocialAuthUser` etc

Comment: I tried to debug using break points..`SocialAuthUser` is Nothing.

Comment: The bigger question is why put it in a web service?

Comment: `getAccIDFromSocialAuthSession()` fuction is in a class file..i am just trying to call it from a web service..anyway what do you suggest?

Comment: Reason i asked 'Why?' as webservice is that if you're not calling it from any AJAX or trying to expose your methods to the outside world then don't use the web service. Create your own classes instead that can be used around the site.

Comment: I am calling it from an AJAX function.

Comment: Ok - updating my answer - give me 2 mins

Comment: Your latest update would definitely work, but i call the same code from multiple places, so i would have to write the same code in almost every page.Anyway, check Andrew Morton's answer. It solved my issue. Thanks a lot for the effort and time you put into this.